# Keyless OIDC AWS EKS <-> GitHub Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, amazon-eks

I am now trying to deploy yaml(helm) to AWS EKS using github actions.
We have added oidc for github to the trust relationship for the IAM role (git-deploy) to be used in AWS, and have given the role permission to upload ecr and full permission for eks. Also, I modified the eks config map (aws-auth) to add group:master for the role (git-deploy).

Currently, deployment to eks with github actions works normally, but the question is as follows. I granted group:master in the config map, but I wonder if I need to grant the actions permission (eks:*) for eks in the IAM role, or if I need to grant the iam role instead of modifying the config map. What's the difference between these? Also, is it not necessary to add a trust relationship for eks to the role?